# Uploading File Directly To Azure App Service that are not part of the deploy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a situation where we have rewritten a website and deployed it to an Azure AppService and things are working as expected. I am using an Azure CDN for related reference pdf files that are pulled from site links and all is good.

The problem I have is that the creator of the pfd files hard-coded links to other documents in the pdf files. These links point to a local site folder, so for instance, there would be a link in the doc to another doc at this endpoint https://mysite/download/filename.pdf.

What I need to be able to do is create a copy of these files on the Azure AppService until the files can be rewritten so they can continue to be accessed as if they were on the original local site folder of the old server.

I am hoping I don't have to include these as part of the deployment because it's over 300mbs of files. I know there is a way to FTP but that is not creating any new folders or files on the site root. I have already tried that using filezilla. I also used Powershell through the browser and that allowed me to create folders and files uploads but they weren't accessible via the hostname/download/filename that is expected. When I navigated to where all the dll are using PowerShell, I was not allowed to create a folder there which is what I would consider the real site root. Does anyone have any ideas what I'm missing?

Update:
I forgot to mention we are using CI/CD through Azure DevOps for our deploys.

Answer (score 0):

> Uploading File Directly To Azure App Service that are not part of the deploy

You could try to use the Kudu api with an azure powershell task in your release pipeline and run kudu api:

```
$WebApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name '<appname>' -ResourceGroupName '<resourcegroupname>'
[xml]$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $WebApp
# Create Base64 authorization header
$username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
$password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$bodyToPOST = @{  
command = "md components"
                 dir = "D:\home\site"  
}  
# Splat all parameters together in $param  
$param = @{  
            # command REST API url  
            Uri = "https://<appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"  
            Headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  
            UserAgent = "powershell/1.0"  
            Method = "POST"  
            Body = (ConvertTo-Json $bodyToPOST)  
            ContentType = "application/json"  
}  
# Invoke REST call  
Invoke-RestMethod @param
```

Then deploy your app using kudu api:

```
$param = @{  
            # zipdeploy api url  
            Uri = "https://<appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/components"  
            Headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  
            UserAgent = "powershell/1.0"  
            Method = "PUT"  
            # Deployment Artifact Path  
            InFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\<artifacts_alias>\drop\<artifacts_name>.zip"  
            ContentType = "multipart/form-data"  
}  
# Invoke REST call  
Invoke-RestMethod @param
```

You could check the document [Deploy To Azure (Platform As A Service) Websites Using Kudu REST APIs](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-to-azure-platform-as-a-service-websites-using-kudu-rest-apis/) for some more details.

The reason why the FTP not create any new folders or files on the site root should be that the uploaded File task is going to upload to is owned by the root user, and can only be written by root by default. If other users need to upload files, permission restrictions and cannot be operated.